# "git rebase master" is finding conflicts in files only in my branch and not master

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge-conflict

Here is my problem:

1. I branched off `master`, naming the branch `other_branch`.
2. I worked a long time on my branch, rebasing daily
3. we tabled the project for a month
4. somewhere during that time, it appears someone else directly manipulated git history on master. squashed, edited and drop commits.
5. I try to rebase with master and get tons of conflicts--most of them involving files that are only in my branch. Someone suggested that because the file isn't on master, that of course it's a conflict. I am mystified by that statement.

Worse yet, this is in commit 61 of 147. So fix the conflicts, rebase continue, fix the same conflicts again, rinse and repeat.

I attempt just a merge rather than attempting the rebase and that seemed to work but this morning when I went to do my daily rebase it is broken again or maybe still and I *thought* I fixed it.

I also tried going through my branch to squash commits but when I got the last merge, I could no longer squash anything. I mean, in this case I couldn't.

Here's my workflow to rebase:

```
git checkout master
git pull master
git checkout other_branch
git pull other_branch
git rebase master
```

So I can avoid any further downvotes:

I have googled the heck out of this and found nothing that fixes my issue.

Here are the things I've researched in no particular order:

- identifying ancestor branch to make sure I branched correctly.
- git conflicts on files that are being ADDED
- git conflicts on rebase
- rebasing across merges
- change branch ancestor
- general git interactive rebase to make sure I wasn't screwing THAT up. nope.
- apply patch of git diff
- more things...

If there's more info you want, let me know

Comment: My initial guess would be line ending changes. Do you have an example of such conflicts? Is it everyone of those commits?

Comment: That's a great question. Some of them have zero differences when I open them, but some of them do have conflicts in them.

Comment: The fact that it _doesn't_ exist on `master` is _why_ you have a conflict there... in the commit that is being rebased at the moment there is a change on file X.... but the file is _not_ in the branch you are rebasing onto... what can `git` do? Just assume that it is ok to disregard that change? It would be too gutsy to assume that... so git will stop and ask _you_ to figure out what to do... it might be ok to tell git to delete  the file (in which case you are disregarding the change).. but _perhaps_ the change belongs in a different place instead of the missing file for this base branch.

Comment: so my understanding that once I'm on my branch and do `git rebase master` it just lays my commits over the top of the most recent master? I must be misunderstanding something critical here. I would think new files in my branch would be a trivial merge--it doesn't conflict with anything because it's new.

Comment: As things stand, you are probably just throwing away 100 points of rep, because you haven't given anywhere near enough information to make the question answerable. If you don't know the rules for what constitutes a merge conflict, or for what a merge is, or for how a rebase is nothing but a sequence of merges, that's easy enough for you to research and too broad for a meaningful answer here. If you want an answer about _this_ particular situation, we'd need to see some _details_.

Comment: nice downvote. I DID research this. For several days. I found nothing that helps with my situation. Can't believe I've got to say that

Comment: Incidentally, checking out master just to pull it before returning to other_branch is quite silly. So the only "code" you've actually shown (something you actually said to Git) is bad code.

Comment: A little more help: how can I make it easier for you to follow. I know the rules of a merge. If the file is on my branch and not master and I'm rebasing MY branch to master, there should be no conflicts.

Comment: How many commits are in your branch and on master? What do `git log --oneline --graph master..mybranch` (only your commits) and `git log --oneline --graph mybranch..master` (only master commits) show?

Comment: 124 in my branch and 6 in master. And the output looks strange. it's like the output is duplicated. Once with the commit line with a * in front and another w/o it.

Comment: This is not what you asked, but it might be a lot easier to reverse-merge instead of rebase. Sure you'll still have conflicts, maybe, but at least it will all be once-and-done, and the overall effect (as far as the state of the branch goes, and the way a pull request will look) will be the same.

Comment: Okay I'll. look at that. This is what I meant to ask, but probably worded it poorly.

Comment: Does your branch _add_ the files causing conflicts, or does it _change_ them?  Added files should not cause conflicts.  But rebasing a change to a file onto a branch where that file does not exist certainly _should_ produce conflicts.

Comment: Yes, that's the situation I'm struggling with: in my branch I am adding a file, and during the rebase there's a conflict in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work on a branch starting from another local branch, it is better to *not* update that other local branch (here `master`: no `git pull master`)

That is because you have no idea how the *remote* `master` can evolve (as you said: "it appears someone else directly manipulated git history on master. squashed, edited and drop commits.")

When you want to rebase your own local working branch, you need to rebase only *your* commits, the one created in `other_branch`.
And you need to rebase it on top of the `origin/master`: the updated remote tracking branch (your local `master` remains unchanged, as your original starting point)

From:

```
...m--m--m--m        origin/master


...m--m--m           master
          \
           o--o--o   other_branch
```

```bash
git fetch
git rebase --onto origin/master master other_branch
```

To:

```
              o'--o'--o'   other_branch (rebased)
             /
...m--m--m--m              origin/master


...m--m--m                 master
```

That way, you are sure to rebase only your commits on top of the updated target branch `origin/master`.
Once you have done so, you can update your local `master` branch, in order to have a new starting point for your rebased branch `other_branch`.

```
git branch -f master origin/master
```

```
              o'--o'--o' other_branch
             /
...m--m--m--m            origin/master, master
```

And you can go on working from there.

---

If you update `master` first, then your rebase will include an untold number of commits, from your `other_branch` HEAD all the way back to whatever master has been rewritten to.

```
...m--m--m--m              origin/master, master
    \
     \
      ...m--m--m           Those commits should not be rebased
                \
                 o--o--o   other_branch
```